# Inverse a matrix in objective c

Tags: ios, matrix

I'm using my own version of glkkit header files so to work in iOS 3.2 and higher, does anyone know how to inverse a matrix4 easily in c?

Ideally I'm just looking for a c version like glkit so I can inverse a matrix4x4 for 3d work. The glkkit has these functions but only works on ios5+, and the inverse method is weirdly hidden from view in the apple glkit header files. Could anyone please lend some help?

Comment: You can get a formula for calculating the inverse matrix from [here](http://www.cg.info.hiroshima-cu.ac.jp/~miyazaki/knowledge/teche23.html), the implementation and learning the theory behind it is up to you.

Comment: I would suggest a approach like Guassian-Jordan Elimination, where you take {A|I} and try to get {I|A-1}. It works quite great, and can be coded quite simply.